# Extracting a certain part of string in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract a certain part of string in Java using regex.

For example, I have a string `completei4e10`, and I need to extract the value that is between the `i` and `e` - in this case, the result would be `4`: `completei 4 e10`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*" );
        Matcher m = p.matcher( "completei4e10" );

        if ( m.find() ) {
            System.out.println( m.group( 1 ) );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the method I always use.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but you can do:

```
    String str = "completei4e10";

    str = str.replaceAll("completei(\\d+)e.*", "$1");

    System.out.println(str); // 4
```

Or maybe the pattern is `[^i]*i([^e]*)e.*`, depending on what can be around the `i` and `e`.

```
    System.out.println(
        "here comes the i%@#$%@$#e there you go i000e"
            .replaceAll("[^i]*i([^e]*)e.*", "$1")
    );
    // %@#$%@$#
```

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

The `(…)` is a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The `*` and `+` are [*repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) specifier in this context.